# PHP - time adjust

Tags: php

I have a set of time in this format.
01:00:04

How can I adjust the time to deduct 4 second from it?
Was trying to parse it but is the a quick way to do it using datetime or something?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) like this :

```
strtotime("-4 seconds", $reference_time);
```

which will return the timestamp you need.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the format is a typo, but perhaps [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/strtotime) maybe what you are looking for. It should convert it to a UNIX Timestamp where you can add or subtract seconds to it etc.

Comment: Since a UNIX timestamp is just a number of seconds, just do `$ts - 4` to remove 4 seconds from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result in the same format, you could use strtotime() and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to do:

```
$delayed_times = array();
foreach ($original_times as $original_time) {
    $delayed_times[] = date("H:i:s", strtotime($original_time) - 4);
}
```

Now this is assuming you're talking about time in a time-of-day sense. If you have a list of times that are durations, this would break for durations equal to or greater than 24 hours.