# 5 Different Times in PHP

Tags: php

I need to have 5 vars like this:

```
$time1 = "The time now -5 minutes";
$time2 = "The time now -10 minutes";
$time3 = "The time now -20 minutes";
$time4 = "The time now -30 minutes";
$time5 = "The time now -40 minutes";
```

So assuming it's 9 AM, $time1 should be "8:55 AM"

It would be so great if anyone could help me out with this :)

Thanks in advance for every hint,

Camillo

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - time adjust](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323775/php-time-adjust)

Comment: There are plenty of examples of the date/time functions in the PHP reference manual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and then [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format it however you want,

```
$time1 = date("g:i A", strtotime("-5 mins")); // e.g. 8:55 AM
$time2 = date("g:i A", strtotime("-10 mins")); // e.g. 8:50 AM
// ...etc
```

Comment: +1 I love the syntax of [`strtotime()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: @DonCroce, you can use 'g:i A' for the format you have specified. in above.

Comment: @Stoic Good spot, updated my answer to use "g:i A" rather than "h:i A", didn't spot the format in the question was without leading 0 on the hour.

Answer (score 1):

```
$time  = date('g:i A');
$time1 = date('g:i A', strtotime($time) -5 *60);
```

and so on..

Answer (score 1):

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval('PT5M');
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i)
{
  $dt->sub($interval);
  echo "The time is now ".$dt->format('g:i A')."\n";
}
```

Gives:

```
The time is now 5:00 PM
The time is now 4:55 PM
The time is now 4:50 PM
The time is now 4:45 PM
The time is now 4:40 PM
```

Now this is every 5 minutes, but just adjust the `PT5M` to `PT10M`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The nicest way to do time manipulation, presuming you have at least PHP 5.3, is to use the new DateTime functionality:

```
$time1 = new DateTime('-5 minutes');
$time2 = new DateTime('-10 minutes');
```

etc.  You can then use all the functions listed in the manual: [PHP: Date/Time](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Comment: You might as well use `strtotime` if you aren't going to use `DateInterval`, in terms of compatibility.

Comment: @konforce "You can then use all the functions listed in the manual." I probably should have stressed how much more pleasant an experience that will be.

Comment: I was just pointing out that the "-5 minutes" by itself is not the new functionality, since that's simply `strtotime`. Otherwise, in the big picture, I agree that the 5.3 date functions are much nicer to use.